# How to add new keys to a GlobX state?

Tags: javascript

When using GlobX and I created this store:

```
const myStore=newStore({
  key1: 'hello'
})
```

Later in my code I wish to add a new key to the store? how should I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using GlobX you don't have to define all the keys in advance. You can update the state and add new keys whenever you want during the lifecycle of your app.

E.g.:

```
state.key2='Hello'
```